# iOS: Installing Parse 1.7.1 error: 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAccessToken.h' file not found

Tags: ios, parse-platform, sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm installing the latest parse sdk and get the following error when trying to build:

FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAccessToken.h file not found

Any solutions?

Cheers

Comment: also getting this error with FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManager.h not being found either

Comment: Did you add the Facebook iOS SDK?

Comment: I dragged the entire contents of the parse-library-1.7.1 into my project and I have a previous version of the Facebook SDK installed already

Comment: same issue..... as @ryder

Comment: I ended up deleting the files and reverting to cocoapods - makes sense in the long run

Answer (score 0):

The same issue with `<FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>`
I've simply remove `Modules` folders from the frameworks bundles because the error message was: `can't build module FBSDKCoreKit` and this helps me. I can do it only from Terminal utility. My app works without this folders.
It is very strange but SDK samples work fine without removing. I think that there is some parameter in configurations but adding configurations from samples to my project also did not help me.